# AngularJS "407 Proxy Authentication Required"

Tags: angularjs, cordova, proxy, icalendar, http-status-code-407

I started working in a company where the network is ruled by a proxy. I already spent a lot of time just figuring out how to re install cordova and ionic while dealing with the proxy, and now Im struggling on this problem :

In a service Im retrieving data from an .ics file, that I parse to json and display in my view. At home or anywhere else it works fine but here, the proxy is blocking the process and says : 407 : "Proxy Authentication Required".

Here is my service

```
angular
.module("service")
.factory("edt", edtService);

function edtService($q, $http) {

var urlCalendar = 'https://planning.univ-tln.fr/Telechargements/ical/EdT_'myNameHere'.ics?version=14.0.2.1&idICal=29B629A9A9CD62183CF9858588E734D7&param=643d5b312e2e36325d2666683d3126663d31';

this.getCalendar = getCalendar;

function getCalendar() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(urlCalendar).then(_parseIcs, deferred.reject);

    function _parseIcs(success) {
        var calData = window.ICAL.parse(success.data);
        return deferred.resolve(calData[2]);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}

return this;
}
```

I already had to specify proxy settings in some files (like .bowerrc and .npmrc, for installing cordova and ionic) but I don't see where to specify the use of a proxy in angular $http...
Any help is welcome :) I tried my best to be clear..

EDIT: Maybe I can work with interceptors? just an idea..

Comment: can you access the mentioned url from outside?

Comment: @nitishkumar-singh yes I can access it !

Comment: I really need help on this one... don't even know where to start :/ and I can't go further and process the data :(

Comment: from outside I mean can you access it outside from your organization

Comment: Yes sure ! As I said, its working alright anywhere else outside ( and on my device, my computer...). And I can access the link itself out of the application (while being in my company).

Comment: when you run it via Ionic serve, does it works?

Comment: ahah thats exactly where it doesnt work ! Actually Im always working and watching with ionic serve, and thats where I got the problem (error happening only in company, just to be clear again)

Comment: One weird thing to note is that Im also retrieving different data in another service, using $http too, but for this case it works alright. I dont understand why here there is a problem. The type of retrieved data (here from .ics) is involved I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was kind of my bad... I was indeed using a specific proxy for connection (in 'internet options/network settings/proxy') and by unchecking it and checking 'automatically detect settings', it now works fine ! I feel so dumb right now... :)
Problem solved, thanks @Nitishkumar Singh for your time tho !